# Expected 'End' vbs error

Tags: vbscript

My code is apparently not working, can you help? Its for school project.

```
x=msgbox("Hello. Make sure you dispose of this computer properly. You can donate to a local school, retirement home, charitable organization, or a community center. You can recycle it or resell it. Let's protect our enviornment one piece of tech at a time. Our tech. Our future. Our job.",1,"Proper Care")
If vbCancel then
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("http://bestanimations.com/Military/Explosions/earth-explosion-animated-gif-2.gif")
    If vbOK then
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("https://www.cta.tech/Consumer-Resources/Greener-Gadgets/Recycle-Electronics.aspx")
        x=msgbox("If you don't, we might have a horrible future.",16,"Help the environment")
    End If
```

Comment: Like the says, you're missing an `End If`. Each `If ... Then` statement must end with `End If`. But honestly, even if you fix that issue the logic still looks wrong and probably won't do what you expect.

Comment: @Lankymart - not all "If" statements require a corresponding "End If".  The indentation of the code sample, may throw people off.

Comment: @enigmaker You are right-*ish*, but with the way their code is written *(first `If` spanning multiple lines)* an `End If` is expected hence the error `Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected 'End'`. A single line `If` is possible but their code doesn't reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If x=vbCancel then CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("http://bestanimations.com/Military/Explosions/earth-explosion-animated-gif-2.gif")

If x=vbOK then
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("https://www.cta.tech/Consumer-Resources/Greener-Gadgets/Recycle-Electronics.aspx")
        x=msgbox("If you don't, we might have a horrible future.",16,"Help the environment")
End If
```

Comment: Use of the vb Constant names (e.g. - vbOK and vbCancel) assumes the system upon which it is executed recognizes such, OTHERWISE, you can use "IF x=1 then {do something, for OK} and IF x=2 then {do something, for CANCEL}."  Let me know either way, if this helps.

Comment: Thank you man, exactly what I was looking for, I just started VBS and its kind of weird. I used to do linux  and C++

Comment: There is no reason not to use the Named Constants as they are built into the runtime, only constants from other libraries like ADO, CDO etc have to be explicitly defined *(I would never recommend [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)))*.

Answer (score 0):

You have two `If` statements, but only one `End If` statement. I'm guessing you may want your second `If` to actually be an `ElseIf`.

Also, saying `If vbCancel` doesn't do what you think it does. If you're trying to test the value of `x`, then you need to be testing the value of `x`.